# How can I choose my OS from the bootloader without a keyboard?

Tags: ubuntu, windows-10, multi-boot, bootloader, touchscreen

I've partitioned the hard drive on my Surface and installed Ubuntu on it. Touch works perfectly in Ubuntu, but the Grub bootloader still requires the keyboard, preventing me from choosing my OS without hooking up the type cover. Is there any way to choose my OS without a keyboard attached?

Comment: I don't even think the Windows boot loader is touch enabled

Comment: Oh, really? I was pretty sure it was. It shares the same format as the special boot menu, which is touch enabled.

Comment: Getting a bit old but - http://stackoverflow.com/questions/15419236/adding-touch-sensitivity-to-grub-2-boot-loader

Comment: I have a surface but literally have never booted into the firmware or boot loader

Comment: @davidgo Yeah, I read that one.

Comment: Sorry, questions that ask for software recommendations are off-topic here because they tend to go out of date quickly. You might try [softwarerecs.se] after going through their help.

Comment: @BenN What if I change it to "How can I choose my OS from the bootloader without a keyboard?"

Comment: That ought to do the job. Ping me again when you've adjusted the question and I'll retract my close vote.

Comment: @BenN Alright, I've edited the question.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I discovered that there is an option in the Advanced Security Settings in the Surface BIOS to enable an onscreen keyboard during boot, which allows me to select my OS without having a physical keyboard attached.